# Is there a way to avoid useless if-else clauses inside a loop when selectign from multiple functions?

Tags: python

Suppose we have three functions

```
def sqr(x):
    return x*x

def sqrt(x):
    return math.sqrt(x)

def lin(x):
    return x

a_list = range(0, 100)
```

We need to fill the list with numbers using one selected function like that

```
use_function = "sqr"

for i in range(0, 100):
    if use_function == "sqr":
        a_list[i] = sqr(i)
    elif use_function == "sqrt":
        a_list[i] = sqrt(i)
    elif use_function == "lin":
        a_list[i] = lin(i)
```

However that means that since use_function doesn't change the loop does 99 useless if checks.

I would like to deal with it this way: assign the function to a variable (you could do it with pointers in C) or use something that imitates the behaviour. Take a look:

```
function_variable = sqr

for i in range(0, 100):
    a_list[i] = function_variable(i)
    enter code here
```

What's the best way to deal with such situations? I know that these if checks don't really affect performance, but I feel like I am doing it wrong and missing something.

Comment: Why not just do `use_function = sqrt` and then `use_function(i)`? In fact, your entire loop could be replaced with `a_list = map(use_function, range(0, 100))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you should do.

Either, make `use_function` the function itself, instead of its name, and use it directly.

```
use_function = sqr
for i in range(0, 100):
    a_list[i] = use_function(i)
```

If that's not possible, because `use_function` has to be a string, you should create a mapping of function names to actual functions. There are different ways to do this:

- `functions = {"sqr": sqr, "sqrt": sqrt}` (explicitly map each name to some function)
- `functions = {f.__name__: f for f in [sqr, sqrt, lin]}` (getting the name from the function object itself)
- `functions = {k: v for k, v in locals().items() if callable(v)}` (get all `callable` things from `locals()`)

The last one might be a bit unsafe, but if you have very many functions this might be the easiest.
Then just get the function from the dictionary, like this:

```
use_function = "sqr"
function = functions[use_function]
for i in range(0, 100):
    a_list[i] = function(i)
```

Also, note that you do not need the loop at all. You can just use `map`, e.g.

```
a_list = map(functions[use_function], range(0, 100))
```

Answer (score 2):

Functions are objects you can put in a dictionary. So if you need to map functions to (user-provided?) strings, you can:

```
>>> call = {"sqr": sqr, "sqrt": sqrt, "lin": lin}
>>> call["sqr"](2)
4
>>> call["lin"](2)
2
>>> call["sqrt"](2)
1.4142135623730951
```